# Pushing Arrays into an Array

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php 

$images =[];
$imagesArrays = [];
//The Loop
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'gallery', 
        'posts_per_page' => 100 ) 
            ); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

    if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
            $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );

            /* Loop through all the image and output them one by one */
            foreach( $gallery['src'] as $src ) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="my-custom-class" alt="Gallery image" />
                <?php
            //Creates an Array Gallery Images from the Post
            //Array ( 
            //        [0] => http://velnikolic.com/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file4741298583098-1-1024x653.jpg 
            //        [1] => http://velnikolic.com/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file9221293737060-1024x683.jpg 
            //        [2] => http://velnikolic.com/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file4741298583098-1024x653.jpg 
            //       )    
            $images = $gallery['src'];
            endforeach;



    endif;
    //Push $images arrays into one array
    $imagesArray = array($images);
    print_r($imagesArray);

endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I would like to push the images array into a list of arrays accessible by a key. $imagesArray = array($images); doesn't append the $images array, only overwrites it.

Comment: $imagesArray[] = $images;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your overwriting continuously instead of pushing into array

**Method 1 :**

```
$imagesArray[] = $images;
```

**Method 2 :**

use array_push function like this

```
array_push($imagesArray, $images);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_push()` function like

```
 array_push($imagesArray, $images);
```

Learn more about the Function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_merge!

$imagesArray = array_merge($imagesArray, $images);

This would append the new array to the end of the old one.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

The following quote from the source seems note-worthy :

"If an array key exists in both arrays, then the element from the
  first array will be used and the matching key's element from the
  second array will be ignored."